# IntelliJ branches with description

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide, branch, jetbrains-ide

I am using IntelliJ with git. I'm on a project with various branches

[image]

generally, I must name the branches with the convention that you see in the image.

The problem is that I have the necessity to see at a glance a description of what a branch is for... because I am working on various tasks. For example, I need to see something like `W01-102 (fix bug on modal)`, `W01-213 (add button to main window)` and so on, instead of seeing only the name.
Unfortunately, there isn't an option to add this kind of description

[image]

and other configurations of git doesn't helps. How can I do?

Comment: There is no option in IDEA to add description for branches.
Please feel free to submit your feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to not exist such a feature in IntelliJ.

To make it implemented, feel free to vote my feature request

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265661